# How to save data in different arrays from single array in php?

Tags: php, arrays

[image: Image of Query Results]

I'm using this code.

```
    include('db_con.php');
$query="SELECT retailerData.poster,retailerData.banners,retailerData.tradeLetters,retailerData.stickers ,retailerData.buntings, retailerData.visitDate FROM retailerData INNER JOIN retailer ON retailer.retailerID=retailerData.retailerID WHERE retailer.retailerID IN( SELECT retailer.retailerID FROM retailer INNER JOIN office ON office.officeID= retailer.officeID WHERE office.officeID IN( SELECT officeID FROM office WHERE parentOfficeID IN (
  SELECT officeID FROM office  WHERE parentOfficeID IN (SELECT officeID FROM office WHERE officeName='$var')
  ) ) )";   
$result=mysqli_query($connect,$query) or die ('Query failed');


if(mysqli_num_rows($result) != 0)
{
$data1y= array();
$data2y= array();
$data3y= array();
$data4y= array();
$data5y= array();
$data6y= array();
 while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
      {
           $data1y[]=$row2['poster'];
           $data2y[]=$row2['banners'];
           $data3y[]=$row2['tradeLetters'];
           $data4y[]=$row2['stickers'];
           $data5y[]=$row2['buntings'];
           $data6y[]=$row2['visitDate'];
      }
}


foreach($data1y as $value)
echo" $value ";
```

The query is just working fine but the data from the $row2 array is not being stored in other arrays. The foreach statement is not givingg any output.

Comment: please var_dump($row2)

Comment: I don't get it @Eric

Comment: `echo mysqli_num_rows($result);`

Comment: Sir I want to store data in other arrays. I don't want to display the result only @splash58

Comment: @HK007 displaying the data in $row2 will help us to help you do what you want to do.

Comment: What result  it shows? Your query can have correct syntax but does not return anything

Comment: Even if the row data is null, the foreach statement should echo the spaces around value unless there is an error somewhere....

Comment: @HK007 dumping the data will help debug the script and figure out what's happening.

Comment: @AkinWilliams If data1y  is empty loop will not be even started

Comment: I have added the image of query results. I think it will help you. Please guide me through it.

Comment: @splash58 `if(mysqli_num_rows($result) != 0)` should prevent that

Comment: Please everyone I need help.

Comment: @HK007 instead of echo, use `var_dump(" $value ")` and let us know the output.

Comment: There are no results. Nothing is displayed on the web page.@AkinWilliams

Comment: `WHERE officeName='$var'` should probably be `WHERE officeName='" . $var . "'`

Comment: @Oli this thing works fine I'm using same syntax in another script. Moreover the if(mysqli_num_rows($result) != 0) checks whether the query returns records or not

Comment: @HK007 Write echo 'test'; on line 2 and let us know if you see any output.

Comment: @HK007 so does it return rows?

Comment: Also, add this to the top of the script :  error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

Comment: Sorry guys I was using these arrays to draw a chart. That chart function was actually not letting anything to display. Now echo works fine and data is also stored in arrays . Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get your code to work as it seems to be using the old deprecated *mysql* functions.

Try this:

```
$connection = new mysqli("ip.add.res.s", "user", "password", "dbname");
$sql = "SELECT ....";

if (!$result = $connection->query($sql)) die ("Query failed");

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row2 = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        // do your stuff here
    }
}
```